# Reading the values from session attribute returns only the name in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have a form jsp and on submit it redirects to a success jsp. The inputs to the form elements are to be captured by a session attribute using a value object and rendered in the success page.The code goes as follows,

Form controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userRegistration.htm")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@ModelAttribute("countryList")
public List<Country> populateCountryList() {
    return userService.getAllCountries();
}

@ModelAttribute("communityList")
public List<Community> populateCommunityList() {
    return userService.getAllCommunities();
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "userForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,ModelMap model) {
    userService.add(user);
    return "forward:userSuccess.htm";
```

Success controller:

```
  @Controller
  public class UserSuccessController {

@RequestMapping("/userSuccess.htm")
public String redirect()
{
    return "userSuccess";
```

User Success jsp:

```
User Details
<hr>
User Name   : ${User.getName()} <br/>
Gender      : <c:out value="${User.getGender()}"></c:out> <br/>
Country     : <c:out value="${User.country}"></c:out> <br/>
About You   : <c:out value="${user.aboutYou}"></c:out> <br/>
Community   : 
<c:forEach var="community" items="${user.communityList}" >
<c:out value="${community}"></c:out>
</c:forEach> <br />
Mailing List: <c:out value="${user.mailingList} "></c:out>
```

But actually the output what i get is,

```
User Details 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User Name : ${User.getName()} 
Gender : ${User.getGender()} 
Country : ${User.country} 
About You : ${user.aboutYou} 
Community : ${community} 
Mailing List: ${user.mailingList}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Taoufik and Krisandra thanks for your help. Case conflicts are my trials. First i tried with lower case only. I found the problem. It was due to the version of the tomcat used. My tomcat 5.5 did not support <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>. So i used tomcat7.04

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `model.addAttribute(user);` in the *onSubmit* method, because in the view you dont use form with attribute
`modelAttribute="user"`
if you use form with above attribute, then you dont need `model.addAttribute(object);` because that attribute somehow links with your onSubmit @ModelAttribute("user").

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are defining the model attribute in the controller as user (lower case), but accessing it as User (upper case). Remember Java language is case-sensitive.

Secondly, I assume you have methods getName(), getGender() etc. already defined in your User class, if that's the case, you access the user object fields in the JSP as follows (Java Beans convention) :

```
User Details
<hr>
User Name   : <c:out value="${user.name}" /> <br/>
Gender      : <c:out value="${user.gender}" /> <br/>
```

I hope this helps